# ¿Por qué "habría" en algunas oraciones no condicionales suena raro y hubiera, había o haya no?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, concordancia-verbal

Navegando me encontré con esto:

http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wGQzWIbBzjaJNlJg

A mi variedad de español le suena equivocado decir:

**1A)** Lamentó que a su jefe no le **habría** gustado el trabajo.

Usaría "no le hubiera gustado" o "no le haya gustado" sin ninguna duda:

1b) Lamentó que a su jefe no le **haya** gustado el trabajo(o 'no le gustara')

1c) Lamentó que a su jefe no le **hubiera** gustado el trabajo.

A diferencia de:
2ab) Me {**habría** ~ **hubiera**} gustado trabajar con él.

Donde pienso que ambas a)habría y b)hubiera son igualmente correctas o al menos usadas.

También he escuchado algo como:
3) Última noticia: Se dice/Se rumorea que no le **habría** gustado su comportamiento.

Donde sí me suena bien.

También en el caso de:
**4A)** Creí/Creía que X ya **habría** llegado, llamé a su casa pero no contestó nadie!

Acá también me suena equivocado 'habría', diría:

4b) Creí/Creía que X ya **había** llegado, llamé a su casa pero no contestó nadie!

Pero entiendo que tal vez es algo literario o regional?

Diría "Ya habría llegado" si se dice en condicional:
5) Si X respetara tus normas, ya habría/hubiera/hubiese llegado.(=ya estaría acá)

¿El uso de habría en **1A)** y **4A)** se usa normalmente en alguna parte? Porque lo he visto usado pero me suena incorrecto o como que no calza. No pregunto sobre si hubiera debe o no ser usado en condicional, pregunto si 'habría' se usa en los ejemplos **1A)** y **4A)** los cuales no son ejemplos de oraciones condicionales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas en las últimas tres frases de tu enlace, explícitamente aparece: "... la preferencia de hubiera por habría es mayor en el español americano que en el europeo, se admiten ambas en uno y otro"

Concretamente, el 4A lo oigo de manera cotidiana en España. Así que creo que sí es regional.

Sobre el 1A la [Fundéu dice que es un error](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/hubiera-por-habria-23847/).

Comment: Cada vez que lo leía sinceramente pensaba que era un error demasiado evidente o que era una traducción de un extranjero, pero ahora sé que es algo regional, pero que me dices de 1A?

Comment: El 1A no, y la Fundéu dice que está mal: https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/hubiera-por-habria-23847/